# How can I put min & maxDate for coconn & DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, cocoon-gem, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I would like to put min & maxDate for my cocoon generated DateTimePicker.
In my app, I could manage putting unique id for my cocoon generated html.

In my code,

- DateTimePicker works OK.
- if you put something like "#new_id'+num" in my dp.change code ,
  you cannot fire and error occured .
  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'minDate' of undefined

I need to put minDate & maxDate for my cocoon generated DateTimepicker.

How should i do?

```
var num = 0;
$(function() {
$('#tickets').on('cocoon:before-insert', function(e,ticket_to_be_added) {
 ticket_to_be_added.fadeIn('slow');
 ticket_to_be_added.attr('id', 'new_id'+ num);
});
$('#tickets').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e,added_ticket) {
 set_datetimepicker();
 num++;
});
}
```

and set_datetimepicker(); is below

```
function set_datetimepicker(){

var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6);
var y = new Date();
y.setDate(y.getDate() + 365);
var a = new Date();
a.setDate(a.getDate());
var b = new Date();
b.setDate(b.getDate() + 365);

       $('#new_id'+num+' .datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm',
                    showClose:true,                    
                    useCurrent:false,
                    minDate: d,
                    maxDate: y,
                    stepping: 15,
        });      

        $('#new_id'+num +' .datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm',
                    showClose:true,                    
                    useCurrent:false,
                    minDate: d,
                    maxDate: y,
                    stepping: 15,
        });      
        $('#new_id'+num +' .datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm',         
                    showClose:true,
                    useCurrent:false,
                    minDate: a,
                    maxDate: b,    
                    stepping: 15,

        });
```

these code below are not work well. 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'minDate' of undefined"
please help me.

```
        $('#new_id'+num +' .datetimepicker1').on("dp.change", function (e) 
         $('#new_id'+num +' .datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });               
        $('#new_id'+num  +' .datetimepicker2').on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#new_id'+num  +' .datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
            $('#new_id'+num  +' .datetimepicker3').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);    
        }); 
        $('#new_id'+num  +' .datetimepicker3').on("dp.change", function (e) {

            $('#new_id'+num  +' .datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);                    

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The cocoon callback gives you the inserted html, so instead of fiddling with the id's, just use it :) You do it correctly in the `before-insert` when setting the id. Instead I propose: do *not* set a specific id and just use the inserted/added html (which is already wrapped in a jquery selector).

So if you hand the new ticket to your function, like

```
set_datetimepicker(added_ticket);
```

then in your `set_datetimepicker` you can just use that (instead of trying to find it again).

```
added_ticket.find('.datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(...)
```

This is theory. Now looking at your code in more detail, I see you have three date-time-pickers, and when they change, they have to change/reflect that in their sibling date-time-pickers.

You could just rely on jquery `.on` functionality, and the relative closeness of the datetime-pickers, no need for callbacks in that case.

So do something like:

```
$('#tickets').on('dp.change', '.datetimepicker1', function(e) {
   $(this).closest('.nested-fields').find('.datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.data);
})
```

So whenever a `.datetimepicker1` is changed, whether it was dynamically inserted or not, if it is inside the `#tickets` div, the given callback will be handled. The callback will first search for the surrounding `.nested-fields` div, and then find the wanted to `.datetimepicker2` so you can set the max-date accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I have another problem so far.

Comment: If the ticket you made is in valid, the datetime you have putted before is visible in views, however, once the ticket expired , the datetime you have putted is invisible in views. How can i solve?

Comment: I do not understand that: how does a user make a ticket invalid? So the user tried to save and is shown his entry is invalid, and then it is invisible? But if it is invalid, thus not saved to the database, how can it expire. Also, if you are referring to the meaning of the dates, i only know of datetimepicker 1-2-3, i have no idea what these dates mean. So please explain in more detail what your problem is.

Comment: I am sorry for my English,.Let me explain again.
for example, If you try to put and save "start_at" datetime(for example 2016/10/22 00:00) by using datetimekeeper  in "new" page form, you can save it and visible in "edit" page form . Because it is future time. but comming tommory , I cannot see my start_at time in "edit" page which I saved. I think I need to something like 
<%= f.text_field :start_at, :value =>"#{f.object.start_at.presence}" %>
but if you try to do this , you still cannot see in edit page.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: typo datetimepicker

Comment: Which datetimepicker library are you using? Check their documentation, it is probably an option to show dates in the past as well (because when entering forms you normally do not allow it).

Comment: Thank you indeed. I am using "gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails'".
I will check